# Stored procedure output into Java custom Object using Spring boot and JPA

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I have created stored procedure to get the data from database and converting the response to Java Object. I am having problem when I am trying to catch the response in custom Object. (NOTE : The example I have given is just for testing. I know there is simple way to perform the operation that I am trying to do it here. But it is just for explanation)

Stored Procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getVersionByName] @name nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * FROM [version] where [name] = @name
END
```

Version Entity  :

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Version.getVersionListedName"
                , procedureName = "getVersionByName"
                , parameters = {
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN,name = "name", type = String.class)})
public class Version {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Repository :

```
public interface VersionRepositoryExtended extends CrudRepository<Version, Long> {

    @Procedure(procedureName = "getVersionByName")
    public Version getVersionListedName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Question :
If you see my stored procedure, there is a 'SELECT * ---' statement. I am trying to capture that output into my Java code as a return value. How can I do that ?

**UPDATE**

When I try to compile the code I get this below error : 
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getVersionListedName found for type Version!

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT id, name` instead of `SELECT *`?

Comment: I am getting this error : org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getVersionListedName found for type Version!

Comment: @Taylor I need to fix this error before I can test it.

Comment: Forgive me if this is wrong but it seems like a stored procedure for this query is a little overkill? You could make the repository method name `findByName` and spring-data should generate the correct query for you based on the method name. See [these docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details) for more details.

Comment: @Taylor I mentioned in question (as a Note) that I have created this SP for test purpose only and I am aware of that solution. Trying out Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 2):

true for Oracle DB

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Version.NamedQuery_getVersionListedName"
                , procedureName = "getVersionByName"
                , parameters = {
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(
                        mode = ParameterMode.IN,
                        name = "name", 
                        type = String.class),
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(
                        mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR,
                        name = "OUT", 
                        type = Class.class)
                  })
public class Version {
    public static final String NamedQuery_getVersionListedName = "getVersionListedName";
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

```java
public interface VersionRepositoryExtended extends CrudRepository<Version, Long> {

    @Procedure(name = Version.NamedQuery_getVersionListedName)
    public Version getVersionListedName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```